# didselectatrow updating multiple cells below reloaded tableview + counter

Tags: swift

This is a two part question the first of which is after up to a full week of trying to figure this out I am still left with a blank. I finally got the individual cells to show the appropriate number related to the selection in the text field but still haven't figured out why the cells being reloaded into the tableview is also showing the updated text field. Basically I just want the text field for cardCounter updated only in the  row selected then if the user scrolls back to where that was if they decided to remove it it is showing them the counter for how many of that object is available.

The second question is I am trying to make a counter for the cardCount that has a total limit of 30 and for each cardCount object selected 1 of those 30 selections has been narrowed down to 29, 28, 27 etc. Just trying to finish up some minor code on my first project.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CardSelectionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var passedDeckObject: Deck?
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var deckCardCount = 30

@IBOutlet weak var cardsListed: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var cardSearch: UISearchBar!


@IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func saveCardSelection(sender: AnyObject) {

    if deckCardCount != 30 {

    let selectmorecards = UIAlertController(title: "Select More Cards", message: "Please Select More Cards To Complete Deck", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okCardAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        selectmorecards.addAction(okCardAction)
        self.presentViewController(selectmorecards, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

    if deckCardCount == 30 {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "All Cards Correct?", message: "Are all the cards in the deck what you wanted?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
        self.managedObjectContext?.save(nil)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        }
    }
}

var costfrc: NSFetchedResultsController!
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}
func listFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let requiredClassName = passedDeckObject!.classSelected.classname
    var requiredCardClasses = [Int]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cards")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    switch(requiredClassName) {
        case "Warrior":
        requiredCardClasses = [1,10]
        case "Shaman":
        requiredCardClasses = [2,10]
        case "Rogue":
        requiredCardClasses = [3,10]
        case "Paladin":
        requiredCardClasses = [4,10]
        case "Hunter":
        requiredCardClasses = [5,10]
        case "Druid":
        requiredCardClasses = [6,10]
        case "Warlock":
        requiredCardClasses = [7,10]
        case "Mage":
        requiredCardClasses = [8,10]
        case "Priest":
        requiredCardClasses = [9,10]
        default:
        requiredCardClasses = [10]
    }
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"cardClass IN %@", requiredCardClasses)

    return fetchRequest
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberofRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    return numberofRowsInSection!
}


//Mark cell displayed with colored text//
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: firstCardDetails = cardsListed.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! firstCardDetails
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards
    var cardCount = 0
    var myDeckCards: DeckCards?
    for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections {
        let myDeckCard = eachDeckCard as! DeckCards
        if myDeckCard.cardsstored == passedDeckObject {
            myDeckCards = eachDeckCard as? DeckCards
            cardCount = myDeckCards!.numberSelected.integerValue
        }
    }




    cell.cardName?.text = listed.name as String
    if listed.cardType.isEqualToValue(1) {
        cell.cardAttack?.text = "*"
    } else {
        if listed.cardType.isEqualToValue(2) {
            cell.cardAttack?.text = "*"
        } else {
    cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue
    }
    }
    if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(1) {
        cell.cardHealth?.text = "*"
    } else {
        if listed.cardType.isEqualToValue(2) {
            cell.cardHealth?.text = "*"
        } else {
    cell.cardHealth?.text = listed.health.stringValue
    }
    }
    cell.cardCost?.text = listed.cost.stringValue

        if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(0) {
            cell.cardType?.text = "Minion"
        } else {
            if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(1) {
                cell.cardType?.text = "Spell"
            } else {
                if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(2) {
                cell.cardType?.text = "Weapon"
            }
            }
    }
    if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(1) {
        cell.rarityType?.text = "Legendary"
        cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    } else {
        if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(2) {
            cell.rarityType?.text = "Epic"
            cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        } else {
            if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(3) {
                cell.rarityType?.text = "Rare"
                cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            } else {
                if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(4) {
                    cell.rarityType?.text = "Common"
                    cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                } else {
                    if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(5) {
                        cell.rarityType?.text = "Starter"
                        cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(1) {
        cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xbe/255, green: 0x23/255, blue: 0x0f/255, alpha: 1.0)
    } else {
        if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(2) {
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        } else {
            if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(3) {
                cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xE2/255, green: 0xA8/255, blue: 0x79/255, alpha: 1.0)
            } else {
                if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(4) {
                    cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xFF/255, green: 0xAA/255, blue: 0x00/255, alpha: 1.0)
                } else {
                    if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(5) {
                        cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
                    } else {
                        if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(6) {
                            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.brownColor()
                        } else {
                            if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(7) {
                                cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xBB/255, green: 0x76/255, blue: 0xE4/255, alpha: 1.0)
                            } else {
                                if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(8) {
                                    cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x9E/255, green: 0xB5/255, blue: 0xFF/255, alpha: 1.0)
                                } else {
                                    if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(9) {
                                        cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                                    } else {
                                        if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(10) {
                                            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                                        }
                                        }
                                }
                            }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
//reload content//
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    cardsListed.reloadData()
}


//selected row functions//
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cardCount = 0
    var myDeckCards: DeckCards?
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards


    var cell = cardsListed.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! firstCardDetails

    cell.indexOfAccessibilityElement(listed)

    // check: is there already a DeckCards object for this Card and this Deck?
    let deckCardsSet = listed.cardselections
    println("The set of DeckCards for that Card is \(deckCardsSet.count)")
    for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections {
        let myDeckCard = eachDeckCard as! DeckCards
        if myDeckCard.cardsstored == passedDeckObject {
            // There is already a DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
            myDeckCards = eachDeckCard as? DeckCards
        }
    }
    if myDeckCards == nil {
        // There is no DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
        // So create one...
        myDeckCards = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DeckCards", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as? DeckCards
        myDeckCards!.cardsselected = listed
        myDeckCards!.cardsstored = passedDeckObject!
    }
    // your code to determine numberSelected here; I'll assume 2!
    cardCount = myDeckCards!.numberSelected.integerValue
    deckCardCount = myDeckCards!.deckcardCount.integerValue


    cardCount = cardCount == 2 ? 0 : cardCount + 1
    myDeckCards!.numberSelected = cardCount
    deckCardCount = deckCardCount - cardCount
    cell.cardCounter.text = "  " + cardCount.description
        if deckCardCount == 30 {
            if cell.selected {
                deckCardCount = deckCardCount + 1
            }
        myDeckCards!.numberSelected = deckCardCount
        myDeckCards!.numberSelected = cardCount
        }
    println(deckCardCount)
    println(cardCount)

}

//searchBar contoller//
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    let requiredClassName = passedDeckObject!.classSelected.classname
    var requiredCardClasses = [Int]()
    switch(requiredClassName) {
    case "Warrior":
        requiredCardClasses = [1,10]
    case "Shaman":
        requiredCardClasses = [2,10]
    case "Rogue":
        requiredCardClasses = [3,10]
    case "Paladin":
        requiredCardClasses = [4,10]
    case "Hunter":
        requiredCardClasses = [5,10]
    case "Druid":
        requiredCardClasses = [6,10]
    case "Warlock":
        requiredCardClasses = [7,10]
    case "Mage":
        requiredCardClasses = [8,10]
    case "Priest":
        requiredCardClasses = [9,10]
    default:
        requiredCardClasses = [10]
    }
    if !searchText.isEmpty {
        // Clear out the fetchedResultController
        frc = getFetchedResultsController()
        // Setup the fetch request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cards")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 565
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText), NSPredicate(format: "cardClass IN %@", requiredCardClasses)])
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        println(fetchRequest.predicate)
        //end//
        //cost fetch request begins here//
        let costfetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "cardCost")
        costfetchRequest.fetchLimit = 565
        costfetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardCost = %i", searchText)
        let costSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "cardCost", ascending: true)
        costfetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        //end//

        // Pass the fetchRequest and the context as parameters to the fetchedResultController
        frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        // Make the fetchedResultController a delegate of the MoviesViewController class
        frc.delegate = self
        // Execute the fetch request or display an error message in the Debugger console
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if (!frc.performFetch(&error)) {
            println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        // Refresh the table view to show search results
        cardsListed.reloadData()
    }
}
//search Cancel
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = nil
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false // Hide the cancel
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder() // Hide the keyboard

    // Refresh the table view to show fetchedResultController results
    cardsListed.reloadData()
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println(passedDeckObject?.deckname)
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "firstCardDetails", bundle: nil)
    cardsListed.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    frc = getFetchedResultsController()
    frc.delegate = self
    frc.performFetch(nil)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Comment: You've got a lot of if else's going on there! I would suggest using a switches for your control flow. e.g. `switch(listed.cardClass) { case 1: ... case 2: ...` etc.

Comment: ah yes I do use switches in other view controllers but this was one of the earlier parts of my project and as such i haven't had time to convert it all yet. Any idea on the related questions though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question #1....

It's usually a bad idea to make cell changes outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (or `prepareForReuse`) when you're using reusable cells.  There are exceptions but, most of the time, that's the safe bet.  The best strategy is to make data changes **only** in other methods and then reload the affected cells (or all of them).

Since cells are cached, changes you make to a cell will show up on the screen whenever that cell is used unless you explicitly overwrite the change when you return the cell.

You should calculate what you need to and store it someplace while in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and then update the display of it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I see hmm I tried doing the changes cell changes in the cellforRowatindexpath area but i got the result that all cells below the changed cell would also change even if the indexpath was used to set it

Comment: I guess that would depend on **how** it was done.  Sometimes people write code like: `if (x) {cell.field.text = @"something";}` and forget to have an `else`, which means the (!x) case has whatever was previously in the cell.  Maybe something like that?

Comment: i tried an if else statement as well as a switch the same thing kept happening i am completely lost on this and i feel it has something to do with core data the way i had it before was something like this I put a card count in the cellforrowatindexpath as well and had the `if cardcount == 0 { cell.cardCounter.text = cardCount.description } else { if cardCount == 1{ cell.cardCounter.text = cardCount.description } else { if cardCount == 2 { cell.cardCounter.text = cardCount.description }`

Comment: How exactly would I explicitly overwrite the changes as per your answer? I have noticed some people not using dequecell calls but i dont know that it would be a good idea for me when I have over 600 objects. That would be a lot of objects and I would imagine the tableview would get bogged down.

Comment: I figured it out this morning in all the code I had the one thing I forgot to add was a set feature making the cell reused set back to 0 so that all the objects not selected actually had something that could be set to. It was a foolish thing. All I had to do was add in the cellforrow method was cell.cardCounter.text = "  " + cardCount.description

Comment: I take it back still not fixed!! I thought I had it