# repeating custom cells label swift with core data

Tags: swift

This is a followup question to a question previously asked before. 
[didselectatrow updating multiple cells below reloaded tableview + counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608336/didselectatrow-updating-multiple-cells-below-reloaded-tableview-counter)
So after much reading and experimenting even after I accepted the guys answer I am still having the same issue. I am going to try a much different approach to it after reading around I found use of adding/removing the index path by having a `Set <NSIndexPath>()` var that I am constantly checking.

After much experimentation I finally got a working check on the `Set <NSIndexPath>` the problem is for some reason in xcode 7 when I try to create a second array to capture the integer values related to the set xcode freezes up on indexing. Which is altogether a different issue. How do I go about keeping track of not only the indexpath row but also the counter as well? My latest code to insert/remove indexpaths at row is:

```
if indexCount == 1 || indexCount == 2 {
    CountIndex.insert(indexPath)
    } else {
    CountIndex.remove(indexPath)
    }
```

My latest try was to try creating a dictionary that stores the indexpath + the Counter in a dictionary like so var `cardCountindexCount = [NSIndexPath: Int]()`
Then setting it in the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {` by `cardCountindexCount = [indexPath: cardCount]`. However I am lacking any experience on going about this approach as it is all experimental and it seems that what I get when I try to recall this is a similar problem. Instead of actually changing the text label in the didselectatrow I am now trying to change it in cellforrow method and creating a universal variable that can store the data changes.

I am willing to admit I am slightly out of my depths on this problem as I have only ever worked with simple tableviews prior. More guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: anyone at all on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up fixing this was by setting the relationship in core data, then saving the quantity of the card in core data, and finally recalling the object relationship and quantity back into the func tableview willDisplayCell method showing the changes in text in that method.